# Spark history UI failing to load all the completed and incomplete jobs on Datastax 5.1 cluster,Spark Version : 2.0.2.15

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have 6 node Datastax 5.1.x cluster with Spark, I try to enable Spark history server, I have configured in all the node. 
why Spark history UI doesn't shows completed job?

```
    # Spark-defaults.conf 
    # Enable event log


spark.eventLog.dir file:///var/lib/spark/worker


 spark.eventLog.enabled true
 spark.history.fs.logDirectory dsefs:///spark/events
 spark.history.fs.update.interval 30s
 spark.history.retainedApplications 50
 spark.eventLog.permissions=777
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled true
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval 1d
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge 7d
```

Comment: have you started it?

Comment: Yes, Alex, I have started, dse spark-history-server start on all the nodes. Its doesn't shows all the completed jobs.